# nhibernate one isession same idbconnection

Tags: nhibernate, isession, idbconnection

I have some code doing 2 times session.Get(id) on the same ISession. I can see that the ISession creates 2 idbconnections. I guess this is because of some kind of configuration. I would like it to do the fetch on the same idbconnection. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `Get` operations are in the same transaction, they will share the same `IDbConnection`. Otherwise you end up with implicit transactions and NHibernate will open and close an `IDbConnection` for each query. In general, you should try do something like:

```
using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    var customer = session.Get<Customer>(123);
    var order = session.Get<Order>(456);

    // do stuff

    tx.Commit();
}
```

[Use of implicit transactions is discouraged](http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/DoNotUseImplicitTransactions):

> When we don't define our own
>   transactions, it falls back into
>   implicit transaction mode, where every
>   statement to the database runs in its
>   own transaction, resulting in a large
>   performance cost (database time to
>   build and tear down transactions), and
>   reduced consistency.
>
> Even if we are only reading data, we
>   should use a transaction, because
>   using transactions ensures that we get
>   consistent results from the database.
>   NHibernate assumes that all access to
>   the database is done under a
>   transaction, and strongly discourages
>   any use of the session without a
>   transaction.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this works fine. But isn't it possible to have long living idbconnections without an transaction?

Comment: Found it connection.release_mode = on_close do what i want.